# Generic type T hiding type

Tags: java, generics

There are numerous questions on this issue. However, my particular case does not deal with interface declarations but rather method return types. The java documentation on generics used with methods says this is legal: `public <T> boolean isType(ArrayList<T> a) {` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

However, i get the error `The type parameter T is hiding the type T`

The code itself functions fine, but my question is, what is actually happening here? Should I be paying any mind to this/does this pose problems down the rode...?

Here is the code in full:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Generics<T, K> {

   private T obj1;
   private K obj2;

   public Generics(T obj1, K obj2) {
       this.obj1 = obj1;
       this.obj2 = obj2;
   }

   public T getObj1() {
       return obj1; 
   }

   public <T> boolean isType(ArrayList<T> a) {//Error on this line
       return a.equals(obj1); //I realize this does not get the type.
   }

}
```

I appreciate the help

Comment: If the goal of this method is to check that the type of the list is T, you may not use the same Generic letter, this has no sense, unse another one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already using `T` in declaration of your generic class. You need to use another alias for the method like

```
public <U> boolean isType(ArrayList<U> a) {
    return a.equals(obj1); 
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. If I "were" to leave it the way it is (I wont), would the code still be fine? Or, would there be unforeseen ramifications.

Comment: From the name of the function, I would have say that the purpose of the method is to check that U and T are same type, not that obj1 is an ArrayList containing the same elements as 'a'

Comment: @Matthew the code is not fine because the method's name is unclear, and make think of other purpose

Comment: Ah yes I know azro, the method name is just a placeholder for some testing stuff I was doing. It should be named something like "checkVal" rather than "getType"